# Compress JS and CSS while deployement

Tags: tomcat, ant

I am using ANT to deploy build in to Tomcat Server. I Want to compress the static files CSS and JS only when i deploy to the server.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that as part of the build (using YUI Compressor)

```
<target name="js.minify">
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false">
        <fileset dir="." includes="foo.js, bar.js"/>
        <arg line="-jar"/>
        <arg path="yuicompressor.jar"/>
        <srcfile/>
        <arg line="-o"/>
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*-min.js"/>
        <targetfile/>
    </apply>
</target>

<target name="css.minify">
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false">
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.css"/>
        <arg line="-jar"/>
        <arg path="yuicompressor.jar"/>
        <arg line="--line-break 0"/>
        <srcfile/>
        <arg line="-o"/>
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.css" to="*-min.css"/>
        <targetfile/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Check out this article for more info:
http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/16/

Comment: Is YUI Compressor is open source?

Comment: It's available under the BSD License, so yes it is open source and free to anyone (if that's what you are asking).  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

Comment: Just a quick intrusion—you may also want to look at http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/ for running JSLint from ant.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://www.henke.ws/post.cfm/Minify-CSS-JS-ant-revisited-using-YUI-compressor) about using [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minify JS/CSS using Ant might help you.