# ant compress and override js/css files

Tags: ant, yui-compressor

Hello i am trying to compress all the .css and .js files from a directory and overwrite the original file with the same name(no concatenation)

I am using this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826896/579646 (also tried numerous other tutorials) but it doesn't work.

I tried this

```
<target name="css.minify">
        <apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="${builddir}/${NAME}/site/assets/css" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${builddir}/${NAME}/site/assets/css" includes="**/*.css"/>
            <arg line="-jar"/>
            <arg path="yuicompressor.jar"/>
            <arg line="--line-break 0"/>
            <srcfile/>
            <arg line="-o"/>
            <arg line="-v"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.css" to="*-min.css"/>
            <targetfile/>
        </apply>

        <move todir="${builddir}/${NAME}/site/assets/css" overwrite="true" >
                <fileset dir="${builddir}/${NAME}/site/assets/css" />
                <mapper type="glob" from="*-min.css" to="*.css"/>
                </move>
    </target>
```

and this

```
<target name="js.minify">
    <apply executable="java" parallel="false">
        <fileset dir="${builddir}/${NAME}/site/assets/js" includes="**/*.js" casesensitive="no"/>
        <arg line="-jar"/>
        <arg path="yuicompressor.jar"/>
        <srcfile/>
        <arg line="-o"/>
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*.js"/>
        <targetfile/>
    </apply>


</target>
```

They both seem to fail

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "seem to fail" ?

Comment: Use 'ant -debug -f yourfile.xml' to get more details about what's going on / "seems to fail"

Comment: by fail i mean it doesn't do what i described it should do, i still get the original css/js, not the compressed ones

Answer (score 1):

I did a test directly using the jar, to see why was not working.
I understood that from command line this is the right command options sequence:

```
$java -jar WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor.jar -v -o <destination-file-min.js> <source-file.js>
```

Note that if the path (parent folders) of the destination file does not exists, the library will not create it (java.io.FileNotFoundException).

So, Ant:

```
    <copy flatten="false" includeemptydirs="true" todir="${js.target.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${js.source.dir}" excludes="**/*.*"  includes="**/*" />
    </copy>
    <apply executable="java"  dest="${js.target.dir}" parallel="false" verbose="true" ignoremissing="true">
            <fileset dir="${js.source.dir}" includes="**/*.js" excludes="**/*-min.js, **/*.min.js"/>
            <arg line="-jar"/>
            <arg path="docroot/WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor.jar"/> 
            <arg line="-o"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="*-min.js"/>
            <targetfile/>
            <srcfile/>
     </apply>
```

The Copy before Apply is needed to create the relative path of destination minified js.
**NOTE that targetfile and srcfile are reversed as expected by the jar**.
I pasted only the js part.. for css it's the same.

Comment: it actually doesnt minifies all the js files

Answer (score -1):

I use this for both css and js and it works just fine:

```
<apply executable="java" parallel="false">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}/js" includes="*.js" />
    <arg line="-jar" />
    <arg path="${lib.path}/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" />
    <srcfile />
    <arg line="-o" />
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="${dest.dir}/js/*.js" />
    <targetfile />
</apply>
```

In the js.minify target u shared seems like u're overwriting the js files (look at the mapper tag), be careful with that.

Also in the css u're moving all the css and renaming them after compressing, this can be done all with the yui compressor target (look at my code).

I hope this helps.

Comment: it actually doesnt minifies all the js files.

Comment: It does for me @Android_Rocks, it removes the comments and puts everything in one line as far as I remember, what are you expecting it to do?